# Scheduling processes with C : 1E8, 4E6, 1E7 4E6

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I am understanding a `script scheduling processes`.

What I do not understand is: 1E8, 4E6, 1E7 4E6 used in the for loop and the if condition.

What does that correspond to? And what is their usefulness?

```
void ProcLong(int *);
void ProcCourt(int *);


void ProcLong(int *pid) {
    long i;

    for (i=0;i<1E8;i++)
        if (i%(long)4E6 == 0) 
        printf("   Proc. Long%d - %ld\n",*pid, i);
    printf("############ FIN LONG %d\n\n", *pid);
}


void ProcCourt(int *pid) {
    long i;

    for (i=0;i<1E7;i++)
        if (i%(long)4E6 == 0) 
        printf("   Proc. Court%d - %ld\n",*pid, i);
    printf("############ FIN COURT %d\n\n", *pid);
}
```

Comment: `1E8, 4E6, 1E7 4E6` are double values given in scientific notation.

Answer (score 0):

`(first number)E(second number)` means "mulitply first number by 10^(second number)". So `1E8` is just `100000000`, and `4E6` is `4000000`, and `1.5E2` would be `150`.

The usefulness is opinion-based, but I think the idea is that looking at, say, `1E11` you can tell immediately how many zeroes are after 1 (11, of course), while looking at `10000000000` you cannot (it's not 11 here).